# Help child dealing with soccer jock

Tags: middle-childhood, social-development, sports, competitiveness

My 10-year old started playing soccer about 6 months ago as the new kid in an existing team. His team gets along well for the most part and most the children know each other from school.
As parents we all get along too.

During matches and sometimes even during training tempers will flare. Mostly this consists of mouthing off against a member the other team for pushing or standing too close to the player that is kicking the ball back in the field (I don't know how this soccerrule translates in English.)
But generally they show good sportmanship.

There is one kid who is very mouthy very often. To the other team, to the referee and to his own teammates.
His father is the team coach and he has to repeat the phrase 'Quiet now, Bobby!' very often. ('Bobby' is not his real name)
The kid in question is among the better players, but certainly not the best. He playes in a forward position so he often scores, adding to his ego.

My child has a very hard time dealing with this boy. When my kid makes a mistake or when the other kid is annoyed by something, he just yells at my kid in passing that he is terribly bad at soccer.
Which he is not, but he is among the not so good players in the team, he has way less experience and he is very selfconscious.
The annoying kid will also misbehave against the really good players, but then everyone knows he is full of shit and the target will easily push back verbally and phsically. Yes there is pushing, from what I saw was mostly in jest but it looked as if it could escalate.

We talked about this recently with another teammember and his dad, and aparently the boy misbehaved more in previous years and was send off the field several times for it.
It seems to me the coach (who is also the father of the annoying kid) is trying very hard to be a fair and levelled for the whole team.
I want to help my child deal with the situation and I want to avoid doing something stupid that will make it worse for him.

Up to now I have not done anything but comfort my child.

I think there are many options for acting but I have a hard time deciding how to proceed:

- comfort my child
- give my child directions on how to handle this (but how should he handle it?)
- talk to the coach
- talk to the team
- be the fitful mom and tell the kid off there and then, see what happens
- ....

Comment: Comforting your kiddo won't do anything to fix the problem.

Comment: Coaches kid should be setting the example to the others kids on what being a good team player looks like... That he isn't says bad things about this coach.

Answer (score 4):

This is a great opportunity to talk about who we listen to and what words we take to heart.

A good question is to ask your son why he thinks this boy acts the way he does. Maybe he's having a hard time at home? or maybe he is feeling a lot of pressure to play really well? Maybe someone at home also shouts at him this way? How did he learn to shout and be rude like this?

This is an opportunity to help your son learn about the underlying reasons and motivations for why a person behaves the way they do.

Another potential discussion you can have is about your sons' own self-esteem and motivations. Just because Bobby says something, does it make it true? Where does a person's value come from? What other people think? or because they are inherently a person and people are inherently valuable (you can also add in whatever your world view is here, religious wise.).

Discussing the difference between opinions and fact can help your son separate himself from Bobby's words. What makes a good soccer player? The number of goals scored? Or being a good friend and team mate? What does that look like? Emphasising that someone can be an amazing soccer player, but a bad friend, does that make them someone you want to play with? What about someone who is not excellent, but is a good friend? Bobby is a great example of this.

Your son will encounter many people who say things that are not true, or have negative things to say about him, and these conversations can help your son think critically and objectively about their words and evaluate their importance to himself and his self esteem. This is about building emotional maturity, and while he's only 10, these kinds of discussions can start opening him up to the idea that not everything other people say can be taken to heart, and he can choose what he will listen to and what he will not.

See also the [10 cognitive distortions.](https://www.verywellmind.com/ten-cognitive-distortions-identified-in-cbt-22412)

Answer (score 1):

I'd tell your kid to ignore the problem kid, reassure him that he isn't wrong to dislike the misbehaving kid, and that the adults should be stepping in to fix things; the game is supposed to be fun for everyone, and it's not fun if one kid is insulting other kids.

Are there other parents who feel like you do?  I'd get some parents together and confront the coach.  Tell him that the problem kid is ruining a fun experience for the other kids, and the coach needs to make sure that all his kids are behaving in a  sportsmanlike manner.  The fact that some kids are taking matters into their own hands verbally and physically doesn't not absolve the coach from being an adult and stepping in.

Comment: So far we only talked about this with one other parent  and teammate, unfortunately their opinion is: "Bobby's behavior was worse before and it's just the way he is".

Comment: Then you might have to go it alone.  But it's not right for him to let his son insult the other kids.  They are all there to have a good time, not there to be his child's emotional punching bag.  And being "better" is not good enough.

Comment: Tbh, this depends on the type of insults this kid is throwing and to the extent it affects the OP's child. I am generally, personally, very much against adults interfering in the conflicts of children because it often turns much uglier, but this case seems to me to be an exception as the bully keeps the same behaviour even after being told not to by the coach. This is only bound to repeat, so perhaps it may not be so bad to confront the little bully yourself (Most preferably with a group of other parents).

Comment: Though, once again, I am not sure what the exact extent of these "insults" are, and if they are something minor like calling names (Idiot, stupid, etc.) or actual bullying. The OP might need to analyze this properly and decide their next course of action. I am assuming from the fact that the coach has to tell the boy to quiet down, and the fact that the OP's child is disturbed of it to the point of this question getting authored, it is something severe, but not sure enough to write an answer.